# My JavaScript validation form is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, validation

My validation form is not working and I have no clue why. I tried to solve the errors for hours now but to no avail.

I can't seem to be able to make the JavaScript code to validate the email format although the code for the email validation part appears to be correct (or is it not?)

Also I can't seem to prevent the button from going to a dead link.

Whenever I add the email validation JavaScript code, the whole script is ignored and only that particular part is processed

Below is my code

#### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <title>FORM VALIDATION</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="welcome">
            <p>Welcome to the Ramones fan page!</p>
            <p id="details">Please fill in your contact details below</p>
        </div><!--welcome ends here-->
        <div class="contianer">
            <form id="form" method="POST" action="index.php" onsubmit="return validate()" name="vForm">
                <div>
                    <h5>Name</h5>
                    <input type="text" name="username" class="textInput" placeholder="Username">
                    <div id="username_error" class="val_error"></div>
                </div><!--Name ends here-->
                <div>
                    <h5>Email</h5>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="inputText" placeholder="Email">
                    <div id="email_error" class="val_error"></div>
                </div><!--email ends here-->
                <div>
                    <h5>Confirm Email</h5>
                    <input type="email" name="confirm_email" class="inputText" placeholder="Email">
                    <div id="confirm_email_error" class="val_error"></div>
                </div><!--email ends here-->
                <div>
                    <h5>Phone</h5>
                    <input type="text" name="phone" class="textInput" placeholder="Phone number">
                    <div id="phone_error" class="val_error"></div>
                </div><!--phone ends here-->
                <div>
                    <h5>Address</h5>
                    <input type="text" name="address" class="textInput" placeholder="Address">
                    <div id="address_error" class="val_error"></div>
                </div><!--address ends here-->
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" id="submit-btn" class="btn">Register</button>
                </div><!--submit button ends here-->
            </form><!--form ends here-->
        </div>

    </div><!--wrapper ends here-->
</body>
</html>
```

#### JavaScript

```
// JavaScript Document
// text-fields//

//Execute JS after the page has loaded
window.onload = function(){

    //Get the submit button and add an event listener when the user submits the form

    document.getElementById("submit-btn").addEventListener("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        checkFields();
    });


    //Function that checks all fields on page
    function checkFields(){
        //Select fields by type
        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

        //Add flag to check if email validates
        var hasErrors = false;

        //Reset all errors
        resetErrors();


        //Loop through all input fields and make sure they are not empty
        for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            if (inputs[i].value === '') {
                document.getElementById(inputs[i].name+'_error').innerHTML= "Please enter " + inputs[i].placeholder;
                document.getElementById(inputs[i].name+'_error').style.display = "block";
                hasErrors = true;
            }
        }

        //If no errors check if email is confirmed correctly
        if (!hasErrors) {
            var emailValue = document.getElementsByName("email")[0].value;
            var confirmEmailValue = document.getElementsByName("confirm_email")[0].value;
            //if emails are not equal//
            if (emailValue !== confirmEmailValue) {
                document.getElementById('confirm_email_error').innerHTML= "Emails need to be identical";
                document.getElementById('confirm_email_error').style.display = "block";
            } else {
                //Reset all errors
                resetErrors();
                alert('Your form has been submited successfully');
            }
        }
    }

    function resetErrors(){
        //Select all errors and reset
        var errors = document.getElementsByClassName("val_error");
        for(var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
            errors[i].style.display = "none";
            errors[i].innerHTML = "";
        }
    }
    var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/; 
if(inputText.value.match(mailformat)) 
{ 
document.write ("Thank you, Email Address Valid"); <--------------
document.form1.text1.focus();

return true; 
} 
else 
{ 
alert("You have entered an invalid email address!"); 
document.form1.text1.focus(); 
return false; 
}

}
```

#### CSS

```
/* CSS Document */
html{
    background-image:url(ramoness.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
    font-size:80px;
    color:#FFF;
    height: 100%;
}
.welcome{
    margin-top:-5%;
    margin-left:10%;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#details{
        font-size:50px;
        margin-left:14%;
        margin-top:-5%;
}
#form{
    font-size:20px; 
}

h5
{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.val_error
{
    display: none;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 14px;
}

input
{
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 15px 5px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.contianer
{
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#submit-btn
{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: normal;
    background: none;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    outline: none;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `test()` instead of `match()`. Here is your almost identical example: [code pen link](http://codepen.io/danailvidev/pen/JWXmwz?editors=0010).

Comment: this has helped me a lot, as it has answered my question precisely! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Main problem here is you are **closing** your *resetErrors* function before *mailformat* variable.
That's why that part of your code is not executing.

After making that change, you also need to define a variable *inputText* which you are using, but not defined/declared anywhere.